# BootstrapValidator; Validators?

Tags: javascript

Im using BootstrapValidator and was woundering if there is a validator for filename?
I use exstension and type, but would like to specify filename.
Is that posible? I've been searching the net and http://bootstrapvalidator.com/validators/file/

This is what i got so far:

**JS:**

```
fields: {
        file: {
            validators: {
                file: {
                    extension: 'xls',
                    type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                    message: 'Välj: lkbkom.xls'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: why do you need that for?

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul Now you can upload any .xls file. And you can by mistake take the wrong file with similar filename. I wan't the filename to match for a proper upload.